# Launch Mongock faster so when changelog fails the application crashes before a heath check can pass

Tags: spring, mongock

We recently added MongoCk to our Spring 5 app (using the Spring runner), but are having some issues during our deploys. Our final step in the deploy process is a health check where the deployment server checks a health page every 5s for 5 minutes. Once it gets the correct response the deployment is considered successful and it finishes.

The issue is that MongoCk seems to only start the migration around 30s after the application context loads, resulting in the health check passing and the migration possibly failing after the service was "successfully" launched.

Using a standalone runner might solve this, but we really like the availability of other beans during the changelogs. So is there a way to enforce the changelogs to be processed as part of loading the application context? Or where is this delay coming from, and how can we reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much information, but you are saying that Mongock starts 30 secs after the application context is loaded. That could be happening for two reasons:

1. The most likely possibility is that you are  using runner-type `ApplicationRunner`(by default). This means that Spring decides when to run it after the entire context is loaded. From what you are saying runner-type `InitializingBean` is a better fit for you .
   Please try this:

```yaml
mongock:
  runner-type: InitializingBean
```

2. You have multiple instances fighting for the lock. There is nothing we can do about it, this process is optimised(Although we are improving even more). However, as said, I believe the issue is related with the runner-type